# Need to have two different branches in git, that ignore different files, but that can be merged easily

Tags: java, android, git, merge

I am trying to create a game using LibGDX, however I am coding it both on my phone using AIDE and in Android Studio.

My problem arises that Studio uses gradle, and AIDE can't recognise this so it uses the jar files downloaded and saved in the lib folder.

I have two folders called core/ and android/ that should have identical code.

What I need is to be able to work on my phone, writing code, compiling etc against the jars, and then come home at night, merge my 'phone' branch, into my 'laptop' branch and only get the core/ and android/ stuff merged in, and not have all the jars and stuff copied over. Likewise, in reverse I don't want all the gradle stuff copied into the 'phone' branch.

I've looked up these exclude files but couldn't work out a solution, and in my head I feel like I could probably use a different .gitignore in each branch, but wouldn't the two .gitignores get merged when I do the merge.

I almost feel like I want to ignore the gitignore if that makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

If I've correctly understood the problem, you can use [submodules](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) to do that.

Simply creates four repositories named *core*, *android*, *phone* and *laptop*, then add *core* and *android* as submodules to both the others.

This way, when you are back home, it's a matter of a couple of `git pull` to have them updated, actually you won't require probably to merge anything the most of the times.
Moreover, you don't need any `.gitignore` file to exclude the undesired stuff from the *phone* repository, for it simply won't be pulled in your *laptop* repository.

For further details about how deal with *submodules*, I strongly suggest to read the documentation above linked.

Comment: So I wouldn't need to ever merge the two diff branches?

Comment: You won't have two branches anymore, instead a set of different repositories.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into it, and if it works, obviously give you the tick. I've upvoted you either way for being helpful.